# Cannot share document in Google Drive with 'per file' Auth scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I restricted the Auth scope of my app to per file (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file) to restrict access to files created or opened by the app. This works fine for my own files created by the app. When I share this file with someone else the file is visible and identified as made by my app but cannot be opened by my app: 'file not found'.

If I do the same with full access scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) the shared file can be opened. This scope is not recommended in the documentation though and should not be needed.

This difference in behaviour of these two scopes when sharing is not as I expected or as I can read from the documentation. Is this a bug or behaviour as expected or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this as well

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything.
I've checked this issue, and it's a bug known to the SDK developers.
We'll have to wait for a fix.

In the mean time you can use the full drive scope, or use the drive.file scope, but declare the 'share' feature availability only when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly then I think this bug may now be fixed. The following scenario works for me using scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

1. Account1 : use app to create file.app
2. Account1 : use google drive API to share file.app with Account2
3. Account2 : receives sharing email and clicks to open file
4. Account2 : the app starts, downloads file.app and uploads a change
5. Account1 : reopen file.app and the changes by Account1 are visible

Hope that helps. I can't believe there isn't an issue tracker for a service that seeks to become the world's file-system.